# How to read Custom Attributes from Exchange mailbox in Outlook Add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, office365

User uses Outlook 2013 and has account in Office365. I want to create similar window like Address Book in Outlook. So I have created new Outlook 2013 Add-in to display list of users. The code looks like this:

```
var list = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetGlobalAddressList();
var users = list.AddressEntries.Cast<AddressEntry>()
                .Where(ae => ae.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry).ToList());
```

And it works. But In exchange, mailboxes have Custom Attributes and some of theme are set. I want to display this attributes on my list but I don't know how to retrieve them.

In Powershell you can do this:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity alexB | FL
```

and you can see that this object has properties like "CustomAttribute1", "CustomAttribute2", ... How to do the same in outlook add-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many OutlookSpy craches I found this :) To get custom attribute number 6 you must call:

```
var prope = user.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x8032001E");
```

Attribute:

- #7 = 0x8033001E
- #8 = 0x8034001E
- ...

Comment: Did OutlookSpy crash? What did you do to crash it?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko OutlookSpy crash every time (with my Outlook) when i select "probe unlisted properties", levae the scope as default <0; FFFF> and select type to String8 > OK > dialog is shown (in my opinion this dialog is useless) > OK > properties list is refreshed and Outlook crach

Comment: Contact me at dmitry at dimastr dot com if you need an updated version with the fix.

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for attributes. You may try using any low-level property explorer such as MFCMAPI or Outlook Spy for observing hidden properties.